# Console data is being passed to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologizes for my poor English.
I have a reserve controller

```
        class Checkout::ReserveController < ApplicationController
             def index
             @products = Product.all
            end
         end
```

It's just return all products, but on view:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK478.png)

View:

```
<h3>Escolha a opção desejada</h3>

      <%= @products.each do |pr| %>
        <div class="product">
           <strong><%= pr.name %></strong>
           <p><%= pr.description %></p>
          <span class="price"><%= pr.price %></span>
       </div>
     <% end %>
```

it´s looks like rails console

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake. Don't output the `each`. Should be this:

```
<% @products.each do |pr| %>
```

Not this

```
<%= @products.each do |pr| %>
```

Comment: For some learning experience and/or homework, find out exactly _why_ it behaved that way.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, works fine here. Really, I´m still a rookie with RoR.